# Implementing search page

Tags: asp.net, search

I'm new to ASP.Net and trying to implement a search page in my project.

I created a simple **search.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" MaxLength="250"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" >
....
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the **search.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.Text = Request.Params["q"].ToString();
        BindRepeater(); //reads Request.Params["q"] and fetches data

        txtSearch.Focus();

        this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = this.lnkSearch.UniqueID;
    }

    protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Search.aspx?q=" + txtSearch.Text);
    }
```

**Problem** is that when I type something in txtSearch and hit enter or click search, the page reloads with the old query string and old search results, seems that txtSearch.Text is updated with old Query value before hitting Search_Click

**For Example** if I enter `search.aspx?q=apple` in address bar the page returns correct results and txtSearch's Text = "apple" .. if I type `green apple` and hit enter, page returns `apple` results, and txtSearch's Text = "apple", also the link is `search.aspx?q=apple`

**I tried**

- `AutoPostBack="True|False"` for the TextBox
- `if (!IsPostBack) 
      txtSearch.Text = Request.Params["q"].ToString();`

but I can't use it I guess since I'm posting back to same page, no?

**I also tried**

```
if (IsPostBack && txtSearch.Text != Request.Params["q"].ToString()) 
       txtSearch.Text = Request.Params["q"].ToString();
```

Comment: Not sure why you're doing the work in the `Page_Load`... why not do the work in `Search_Click` and remove the complexity of the reload?

Comment: @freefaller I'm sorry I didn't get what you mean? can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a strange way of doing it to me.

My preference would be to have the search logic in the event handler itself, rather than implementing this strange post-back loop.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        // If passed in on first entry to the page
        var searchQuery = Reqest.Params["q"];
        if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(searchQuery) == false)
        {
            txtSearch.Text = searchQuery;
            Search_Click(null, null);
        }
    }

    txtSearch.Focus();

    this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = this.lnkSearch.UniqueID;
}

protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pass the value of the search to the repeater
    BindRepeater(txtSearch.Text);
}
```

Note that I'm passing the search text to `BindRepeater` so you'd have to update it to use the parameter value rather than query string

Comment: Thanks a million for your time, I'll test it and get back to you

Comment: how can I update the query string with the new search criteria? the address stays the same

Comment: Thank you sir, I kinda "merged" my code and yours and it's working perfectly now